# C++ "OR" conditions being ignored

Tags: c++, loops

I have a loop in my code which looks like:

```
string var = ""
while (var != "q" || var != "Q") 
{
...
cin >> var;
}
```

It does not work, my loop becomes unstoppable. But if I change my code to this:

```
while (var != "q")
```

or this:

```
while (var == "q" || var == "Q")
```

It`s gonna be working. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: var != "q" || var != "Q" is always true.

Comment: When you input `q` you get:  "q" != "q" || "q" != "Q" ==> false || true ==> true and the same when you input `Q` ==> true || false ==> true

Comment: Perhaps your intentions require you to go with 'while (var != "q" && var != "Q")' ?

Comment: @OtávioDécio: Answers in the answer section please

Comment: Thanks, i would never get this logics by myself. I thought it compares to all conditions and becames 'false' statement if one of the conditions is 'false', not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (var != "q" || var != "Q")
```

Written in plain English, this says: While `var` is not equal to `q` or `var` is not equal to `Q` run this loop.

This will always return true because `var` will always not be either `q` or `Q` (it can't simultaneously be both).

Your other conditions work because they're checking the right thing.

```
while (var != "q")
```

While `var` is not equal to `q` run this loop.

```
while (var == "q" || var == "Q")
```

While `var` is equal to `q` or `var` is equal to `Q` run this loop.

The condition you're looking for is to use the `and` operator.

```
while(var != 'q' && var != 'Q')
```

While `var` is not equal to `q` and `var` is not equal to `Q` run this loop. If `var` goes to `q` or `Q`, the loop will exit.

Answer (score 1):

Since a variable can only have one value, it is *always* "not 'q' or not 'Q'".